# flash version mixup in openlaszlo

Tags: flash, openlaszlo

I'm creating my first project in openlaszlo and ran into a weird problem:

- whatever the flash version installed or targeted, I get a dialog telling me to install flash 10.1

I'm then sent to Adobe's page with no possibility to cancel.

Any idea?

TIA

greg

PS: I know this post would be better in openlaszlo forum but they have manual validation...

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, there's an answer here:

http://forum.openlaszlo.org/showthread.php?t=14413